# Zend SOAP server WSDL URI with http authentication

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap

I'm trying to set up a SOAP service using Zend_Soap_Server. (ZF1)
My problem is that the WSDL URI is password protected. It can be accessed by setting 'https://username:password@wsdl.uri' as the URI, but the username and password are different for the development and live versions of the application.
I've tried setting the login and password with `$soapServer->setOptions(array('login'=>$login, 'password'=>$password));` but nothing happens.
How can I achieve this? (if it's possible)

Comment: Looking at the source of `Zend_Soap_Server`, I don't see 'login' and 'password' as options in the `setOptions` function. :(

Comment: Refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63990093/6521116

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) of the `SoapClient` doesn't mention username and password authentication (htpasswd), so I assume that this type of authentication is not possible.