# PHP consume soap service using Basic auth

Tags: php, soap, basic-authentication

I have a server that connecting to it using CURL is only possible using

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
```

Now i need to connect to the same server using SOAP
How is it possible to set basic authentication to soapclient ?

Thanks

Comment: Answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195890/zend-soap-server-wsdl-uri-with-http-authentication). Sadly the PHP SoapClient can't handle http auth.

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/63990093/6521116

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php-soap has a limitation/bug, which does not allow to retrieve the WSDL while using Authentication ([bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=27777))

You can update/upgrade your PHP version. There are people reporting that this bug is solved on 5.4.8 version.

To keep php-soap you must use a local/static version of the WSDL what I DO NOT recommend.

Although it could be less performant, I suggest you to have a look at another PHP Soap Client library, like [NuSOAP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/).

Comment: Ok so now im trying to use nusoap but still getting the same error on $client = new soapclient($url);  This line throws the same error before i have the chance to set the credentials

Comment: @liorr have a look at this post: [NuSOAP-HTTP-Authentication-and-HTTP-Proxy.html](http://www.beanizer.org/site/index.php/en/Articles/NuSOAP-HTTP-Authentication-and-HTTP-Proxy.html)

Answer (score 0):

We were having a similar issue with a JDE connection. The authentication entity WSSE needed to be added along with the wsdl server accepting requests from your server (where the php script lives)

```
$Username = '******';
$Password = '******';
$xmlHeader =
                '<soapenv:Header> 
                        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
                        <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                                <wsse:Username>'.$Username.'</wsse:Username>   
                                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">'.$Password.'</wsse:Password>  
                        </wsse:UsernameToken>
                        </wsse:Security>
                </soapenv:Header>';
```

Some extra envelope information should be set also

```
$this->ch = curl_init( $this->postURL );
                curl_setopt( $this->ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
                curl_setopt( $this->ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 'SSLv3');
                curl_setopt( $this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->postArg);
                curl_setopt( $this->ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
                curl_setopt( $this->ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                curl_setopt( $this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt( $this->ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
                curl_setopt( $this->ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));

                // GET RESPONSE AND RESPONSE CODE
                try{
                        $this->response = curl_exec( $this->ch );
                        $this->responseCode = curl_getinfo($this->ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

                        if($this->responseCode != '200'){
                                //ERROR!!
                        }
                }catch(Exception $e){
                        $e->getMessage();
                }
```

Pay attention to the CURLOPT_SSLVERSION = SSLv3.  You will need to see what version SSL you may need to get access to your WSDL.

Comment: This is just a piece of the xml you should be using to requesting.

Comment: Thanks but my question is about using SOAP

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use 'login' and 'password' from SoapClient constructor options?
They are described here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php

Answer (score -1):

You need to send a soap header with the authentication info :

```
$param = new SoapVar(array('username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password'), SO AP_ENC_OBJECT);
$header = new SoapHeader('http://localhost/soap_server/server.php', 'AuthenticationInfo', $param, false);
```

And then pass it to the SOAP client object

```
$client = new SoapClient($url, array('trace' => 1));
$client->__setSoapHeaders(array($header));
```

Comment: Well I keep getting "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from ..."

Comment: Sorry made a mistake - curl only working with "CURLAUTH_ANY" So i need to set soap headers to CURLAUTH_ANY

Comment: Hmm I think there is a problem with your WSDL. Can you show me the whole error?

Comment: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://domain.com/ServiceName/ServiceName.asmx?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://domain.com/ServiceName/ServiceName.asmx?wsdl

Comment: The problem is that it cannot load the wsld file.

Comment: but when i try reaching the address using a browser with the same credentials im getting it

Comment: Check this post :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861077/soap-error-parsing-wsdl-couldnt-load-from-but-works-on-wamp

Comment: Tried the same solution but i still get the same result (BTW the service is on HTTPS)

Comment: Did you check your firewall settings maybe ?

Comment: Basic auth means http auth on the wsdl file.. so it will fail already on the `new SoapClient(...)` you have to provide it there to the headers of that request

Answer (score -1):

Actually it is possible with standart methods of php-soap.

There is an option called `stream_context`. More info on this here: http://php.net/manual/en/context.php

You should provide a context with Authorization header. Example:

```
$context = [
    'ssl'  => [
        'verify_peer'      => false, 
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
    ],
    'http' => [
        'header' => 'Authorization: Basic ' .base64_encode('user:pass'),
    ],
];
$client = new \SoapClient('wdsl', [
    'login'          => 'user',
    'password'       => 'pass',
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create($context),
]);
```

Comment: That did not work for me. I still get the error it can't connect. I know the server is reachable, as if I try to visit the wdsl url using a browser. it does give me the file after I authenticate.