# PHP SoapClient with BasicAuth

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I have a PHP script trying to connect to a WSDL.
I need to allow self signed AND give basic auth details.
Using SOAP UI, when I connect to the WSDL I am prompted for username / password. 
I got this working.

I also found out that each request also requires basic auth (so on the request screen, I have to select Auth, then basic, enter same credentials as I used on the prompt).

How to I do this auth in PHP
As I said, I can connect, not a problem, I seem to kill the service or timeout if I try to make a request

```
<?php
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
 ));

$data = array(
    'columnA' => 'dataA',
    'columnB' => 'dataB',
    'columnC' => 'dataC');

$url = 'https://111.111.111.111:1234/dir/file';
$login = 'username';
$pwd = 'password';


$client = new soapClient(null, array(
     'location' => $url,
     'uri' => '',
     'login' => $login,
     'password' => $pwd,
     'stream_context' => $context
));
echo "\n\r---connected---\n\r";
$result = $client ->requestName($data);

print_r($result);
?>
```

My output is 
---connected---

Then it seems to hang.
I have tried wrapping it round a try catch and I had the same result.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1):

From the [Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) soapclient support the http basic auth.

> For HTTP authentication, the login and password options can be used to
> supply credentials. For making an HTTP connection through a proxy
> server, the options proxy_host, proxy_port, proxy_login and
> proxy_password are also available. For HTTPS client certificate
> authentication use local_cert and passphrase options. An
> authentication may be supplied in the authentication option. The
> authentication method may be either SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC
> (default) or SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_DIGEST.

```
$wsdl = "http://example/services/Service?wsdl";
$option = array(
    "trace"=>1,
    "login"=>"admin",
    "password"=>"admin",
);
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl,$option);
```

But when I initiate the soapclient, it will throw this error

Exception: Unauthorized

I also have tried to put the auth in the url, like

```
$wsdl = "http://admin:admin@example/services/Service?wsdl";
```

But it also doesn't works.

Finally I solved it by add `authentication` to the option. The manual says the `authentication` default value is the basic auth, but only when I explicitly set it, it can work.

```
$option = array(
    "trace"=>1,
    "login"=>"admin",
    "password"=>"admin",
    "authentication"=>SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try url encoding your username and password inside the url that you are using:

```
$url = 'http://'.urlencode('yourLogin').':'.urlencode('yourPassword').'@111.111.111.111:1234/dir/file';
```

Also I don't see you make use of the wsdl in your code example. You can always download a copy of the wsdl locally and then reference that local copy. You can download the wsdl anyway you want (with php, curl, manually).

Comment: Thanks but I can connect. So parsing the username and pwd on connection won't make a difference. Its making the request. I can't pull request locally as its a third party and we are sending data. And I can't change the auth method as its third party

Comment: When adding them to the url, you are not parsing them, you are including them with each request. By downloading the wsdl upfront you are still connecting to an external url